# Spam filters are effecting email open rate

Tags: email, gmail, tracking

We are using pixel image to track email opens for our application. If a person opens an email its working as expected. But when spam filters opens any email it's also considering as email open and it is effecting our open rate. Is there any way to find if an email is opened by spam filter or by a person. If its not possible is there any good way to track proper email opens and clicks?